# Is the Model View the right choice when the both have to be customized to fit the app need?

Tags: qt, view, model

I'm just starting with Qt and i'm having a doubt if the Model View is the right way to go here.

I have a following object which has to be persistent in some database:

```
Class Car:
{
private:
    Qstring owner;
    bool registered;
    Qstring tires
}
```

The data should have the following view (it's a representation of a object Car):

[image]

My idea was to subclass the `QAbstractItemView` and try to adopt it to the customized `QAbstractItemModel`. The data is much better represented as objects than any of the default models mappings (list, table tree) which is why I can't see the benefits of using the Model View as shown in tutorial examples.

Would the model view be useful here, and what should the model/view costumization include?

Comment: Does your view show only one `Car` item at a time?

Comment: @vahancho Yes. However. in the future i plan to have additional similar objects (Van, Truck, Train) that will have a slightly different view representation but the main elements will be the same (a few radio buttons, check buttons, and text elements). That's why I possibility for reuse i just don't see it clearly. There will always be a single entity shown at the time.

Comment: Thanks. In your case, I think, using Model/View will make sense in terms of using data and corresponding delegates for its editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You look like you're using standard `QWidget` UI elements. These already exist so there's no need to create them again using a `QAbstractItemView`. You can use the QtDesigner instead.

The Model-View pattern still applies though.

You can use the `QStandardItemModel` or your own custom `QAbstractTableModel` to handle the data storage and retrieval, and you can connect the UI with the model using the [QDataWidgetMapper](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qdatawidgetmapper.html)